# Am trying to launch in Cpanel, but am getting a Module not found error

Tags: python, django, cpanel, modulenotfounderror, deploying

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3fGd.png)I'm new to Cpanel and am trying to launch my python Django project, I think I've set up everything correctly but am getting this error:
File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my_module_name>'
[UID:2291][2142962] Child process with pid: 2149437 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0

so I tried rearranging my apps in settings.py, which has led me to believe that the problem maybe due to the fact that, my app are not being identified.
I had created my project using python version 3.9.10, but my cpanel can only support version 3.8.6, so I had to downgrade, and I think this maybe the root of all my issues.

Any help offered would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Take our [tour] and see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i found the answer a few days ago, just forgot to give it here.
So I simply just took all my files one directory back, and voila, problem solved.
Sometimes, I guess when the complex solutions can't work, just take a step back and be a bit simplistic.